# Powershell - Outlook advanced search not recursing through org box

Tags: powershell, outlook

I am trying to put together a small script that finds all emails in an org box that match a given search term and display the full path to each result.
While what I have works in my personal inbox and recurses through all subfolders, when I try and use it on the Org box it only searches the current directory and does not recurse.

Is there something I am missing that is unique to working with Org boxes?

```
$OL = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$NS = $OL.GetNameSpace('MAPI')
$MB = $NS.createRecipient('SomeOrgBox@mail.com')
if ($MB.Resolve) {
    $Inbox = $NS.GetSharedDefaultFolder($MB,[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders]::olFolderInbox)
} else {
    Write-Warning "Unable to access inbox
    "
    pause
    exit
}
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $OL -EventName "AdvancedSearchComplete" - Action {
    if ($Args.Results) {
        Write-Host " - Results -
        "
        Foreach ($Result in $Args.Results) {
            Write-Host $Result.Subject
            Write-Host $Result.Parent.FolderPath
        }
        Write-Host ""
        Write-Host " - End of results -"
    } else {
        Write-Host " - No Results found -"
    }
    Write-Host ""
}

Function Search-Inbox {
    $Search = $OL.AdvancedSearch("'"+$Inbox+"'", "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject like '%"+$Query+"%'", $true)
}

$Query = Read-Host " Enter Search Term "

Search-Inbox
```

Edit:
To clarify, this will be used on Windows machines and third-party tools are not an option.

Also, after some testing, it seems that how the Org box was added to Outlook plays a role in this issue.
If the account is associated with you through your personal account's advanced options, the search does not recurse.
If the Org box was added as an additional Email account through the 'Add Account' dialog recursion works just fine.
If I was the only one using this, I could just change how I have the account set up, but since other people have to use it as well, it's not the most ideal solution. For now, I'll run with it until a solution can be found for accounts set up the other way.

Comment: Why are you not just using the defined Exchange cmdlets, compliance services, eDiscovery or compliance tools for this? It's why they are there. Don't script if the native tool already provides  solution. --- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/mailboxes/search-mailbox?view=exchange-ps - 
--- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/policy-and-compliance/ediscovery/compliance-search?view=exchserver-2019 --
 --- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/keyword-queries-and-search-conditions?view=o365-worldwide, or are you say'n you want this on desktop?

Comment: 3rd party tools are not an option due to policy.
Yes, this is for desktop use.